# Is there any quick way to find occupied height of a container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On fly, there is no.of childrends are appened to the parent. i can able to get the `scrollheight` and add the scroller (custom) in to it.

Looping all children we can get, but any other short way?

I would like to remove the same, when not required. so i would like to know the how much the height are occupied, in there is some space empty, i can remove the scroller.

the main things is i don't know the children height, each children  height as well varies, and no.of children as well unpredictable.

how to calculate how much of the height accupied by my childrens?

i tried like this:

```
var accupiedHeight = $('.blue').innerHeight();
console.log(accupiedHeight);
```

No result.

[Live](http://jsfiddle.net/gf1Ljh8u/)

Comment: Sure gives me a result in the console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate total height of children elements if you clone parent container and set the height to `auto`:

```
var accupiedHeight = $('.blue').clone().css('height', 'auto').appendTo('body').height();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gf1Ljh8u/3/

This way it will look pretty concise. However I would still prefer looping version as it's more comprehensive.

```
var accupiedHeight = 0;
$('.blue').children().each(function() {
    accupiedHeight += this.scrollHeight;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gf1Ljh8u/4/

Comment: The first method seems to be good and easy. But I am wondering still why do you prefer the loop..? (simply we can append and get the height and remove the element right..!)

Comment: Yes, it's simple and you can easily use it, it just looks a little hacky: to get height you create one more DOM element, append it to DOM, them remove. I would prefer loop way, but this is about tastes. I would anyway create helper function.

Comment: can you look in to here.. I integrated your second approach, it's picking up from the nested childrens heights too.. http://jsfiddle.net/gf1Ljh8u/7/

Comment: What about this then if you have nested elements: http://jsfiddle.net/gf1Ljh8u/8/

Comment: This is not includes the margin, it do with padding. http://jsfiddle.net/gf1Ljh8u/8/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, what you are searching is simply jQuerys `.height()` method

> Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements

http://api.jquery.com/height/

This will work if the container has no heigth explicitly set. If the height is explicilty set, wrap the child elements in an extra div and use the .height() method on that.
E.g:

```
<div class="blue">
  <div>
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the js:

```
var accupiedHeight = $('.blue div').height();
console.log(accupiedHeight);
```

Comment: This is not what OP's is asking. He needs to calculate the total height occupied by children elements, not their parent container.

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood the question and updated my answer.